# How to run pytest when app config file is absent?

Tags: python, testing, continuous-integration, pytest, config

I have an Python application with a `config.py` file that contains lots of constants and secrets such as:

```py
...
ENV = "dev"
DEBUG = False
SRV_IP_ADDR = "127.0.0.1" 
API_1_KEY = "xxx"
API_2_KEY = "yyy"
...
```

Many modules of the app depend on it and import constants as needed.

The `config.py` file isn't versioned and each environment (local, production...) has its own `config.py` file.

I'm starting to test my code with pytest and it works locally, but the app code relies on my local `config.py` even if I try to make the test not rely on it.

When launching pytest on a machine that doesn't have `config.py` (ie: GitHub actions runner in my case), the config file doesn't exist and the test fails.

What are the best ways to run pytest in this configuration?

Comment: So the problem is that you don;t want to put the config files in Github because they have confidential information right?

Comment: Yes exactly. The config file mixes non-confidential information (eg: timeout delays) and confidential information (DB credentials, API keys...)

Answer (score 0):

Well it is dependent...

If you write unit tests (and you should!) then your test should not be aware of the config file (use mocks and dependency injection if needed).
But if you writing integration/system tests you need to make sure your config file is the same for all the envs and just the value itself is changing according to the env variables.

for example:

```
import os    
ENV = os.environ.get("ENV")
DEBUG = os.environ.get("DEBUG")
...
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes I'm willing to write both types of tests. I should replace hardcoded variables by environment variables then.